# sendResponse within grails webflow

Tags: grails

I would like to check if a user is allowed to start a flow by checking if parameters are valid. If not I will send an error 404. But in the webflow de error response won't be send.

The webflow always returns status 200.

Does somebody have a solution for this problem?

```
def shortShopFlow = {
        onStart {
                log.info("starting a new shoppingCart traject")
                Boolean isValidShop = shopService.isValidShop(params.code as String, params.token as String)
                sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()

                if (!params.code || !isValidShop) {
                    response.sendError(404)
                    return
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something:

```
MyController{        
  def shortShopFlow = {
    onStart {
            log.info("starting a new shoppingCart traject")
            Boolean isValidShop = shopService.isValidShop(params.code as String, params.token as String)  
            sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()  

            if (!params.code || !isValidShop) {  
                return 404();
            }
           on('404').to ('pageNotFound');
    }
    pageNotFound{
        redirect(action: 'fourZeroFour');
    }
    def fourZeroFour = {
      response.sendError(404);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Minhaj